# Why am I having connection problems with 16.04

Tags: networking

So I have windows 10 (uefi) and I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu. Going through the install is no problem but before I do it I want get my WiFi going. I understand that my WiFi card may not be supported but I have a **tl-wn722n** which from research should be fine for Linux, but here is the problem, when I try to turn WiFi on via menu option it won't immediately activate I have to enable my USB WiFi via terminal then use `iwlist scanning`just to get it working.

Trying to find my WiFi and it is not being seen so what I did was turn my phone to a WiFi hotspot for the computer to connect to. Whenever I try to connect it disconnects instantly.

What I have tried:

Unblock with `rfkill`

`Nmcli` to try to get wifi going

Went through several more sites to read on what to do but my last error seems to be:

```
failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart
```

I am very new to Linux but have never had this problem before when I tried to play with Linux in the past. Please any and all help is appreciated I really want both OS on my laptop.  Vm is an option but I want Linux to have full resources of my computer.